# How to iterate over pandas dataframe row in python and create new column based on values present in row

Tags: python-3.x, pandasql

I have a patient data frame and sample looks like this.

**pat_id     drug      date               lag_date              lag_grace_dte**

1234     A    1-Jan-17        1-Jan-17              11-Jan-17
1234     A    11-Jan-17       1-Jan-17              11-Jan-17
1234     A    26-Jan-17       11-Jan-17             26-Jan-17
1234     A    5-Feb-17        26-Jan-17             15-Feb-17

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIjEL.png)and [required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWd3m.png)
and output should be based on patient id, date and lag_grace_date columns.

Below is the business criteria. I am trying to build a stockpiling algorithm for a patient

If patient '1234' has taken the drug 'A' on 'Jan-01-2017' for 20 days then his next visit_date(date) should be on 'Jan-21-2017'. this should be checked against lag_grace_dte as per the below. If his next date is less than the lag_grace date then we should modify date column as lag_grace_dte +1 for that patient in that row.

```
if date < lag_grace_dte then lag_grace_dte+1 end as mod_date
```

output look like below:

```
pat_id  drug    date        lag_grace_dte   mod_date

1234    A       1-Jan-17    11-Jan-17       1-Jan-17
1234    A       11-Jan-17   11-Jan-17       12-Jan-17
1234    A       26-Jan-17   26-Jan-17       26-Jan-17
1234    A       5-Feb-17    15-Feb-17       5-Feb-17
```

Thanks in Advance.

Below is the code I am trying but it is giving me the date column as output without any change. I am new to python please suggest me on this.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
day = timedelta(days = 1)   
for a,b,c,d in zip(drugs.pat_id,drugs.date, drugs.lag_date,drugs.lag_grace_dte):        
    if b==c:                
        adj_dte = drugs.date        
    elif b<d:                    
        adj_dte = drugs.lag_grace_dte+day        
    elif b>d:                        
        adj_dte = drugs.date
    print(adj_dte)
    break
```

output of the above code:

**mod_date**

1-Jan-17
11-Jan-17
26-Jan-17
5-Feb-17

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  Are you having trouble understanding how to iterate arbitrary code over a pandas row?  If so, the business logic is irrelevant, so show your attempt to iterate and we'll help you sort it out.